# Computer won’t start after blue screen fix

Tags: windows-10, bsod, reboot

I got the “Page Fault In Nonpaged Area' Error” blue screen code and decided to google fixes for it as it was the second time I had gotten it. I followed the first two instructions on [this](https://www.tomshardware.com/news/how-to-fix-page-fault-error-windows-10,36234.html) guide, the two command line codes. The second one worked fine and did it’s job but the first one said I needed to restart for it to take effect. I restarted my computer and nothing happened for an hour I hard rebooted and the same thing happened. I hard rebooted with the reset button and the power button a couple of times, but nothing changed. How can I start up my PC?

Comment: The first two command lines in the article you referenced are CHKDSK and SFC, and both should not break your computer, except you ran the Fix option in CHKDSK and if found and corrected  disk errors, that may have caused the issue.  At this point, after several tries (you did above), try starting with a bootable USB Key, and see if it starts. From there you may be able to recover documents and then re-install Windows.

Comment: @John Is there anything I can do if I can’t access my bios?

Comment: Try starting with a USB key to see if that works.

Comment: @John I put the USB in and started my computer and nothing different happened.

Comment: Then it would appear you have a hardware problem. USB start bypasses the OS and disk, so now Motherboard or memory.

Comment: @John I tried starting my computer with only one of the two sticks of ram in and neither time did it start. Is there a way to tell if it’s just both sticks or my motherboard?

Comment: It is unlikely 2 sticks (both sticks) failed simultaneously so it does appear to be the Motherboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the first command I entered that would run on restart was trying to run, but since it was not displaying through my GPU I could not see and it and it was supposed to take about 6 hours. After I plugged my monitor into my motherboard after finding a cable for it, it showed that it was repairing the drive.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SuperUser. I was just wondering about whether this would be an explanation at all. The only indicator of such a condition - if the screen remains "blank" - would be disk activity, if your machine has the respective lights, or the disk sounds if you have rotating disks.

Comment: @0xC0000022L Can I ask what you mean by that?

Comment: When I was reading your question and the comments on the question I was about to comment who you knew that the machine wasn't still running `autochk.exe` (the native binary that runs when `chkdsk` schedules it for the next reboot). And then I saw your answer and it turned out my hunch was right, because you ran into _exactly_ this condition.